# Show that there is no regular planar graph (all vertices degree 3) so that all regions, including the unbounded region, are hexagonal.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Show that there is no regular planar graph (all vertices degree 3) so that all regions, including the unbounded region, are hexagonal.

I am sure this has something to do with the fact that for planar graphs the sum of degrees of regions is twice the number of edges. Looking for a hint to push me in the right direction.

Comment: The Euler characteristic of a planar graph is $2$. However, if every face is hexagonal and every vertex has degree $3$, $V+F-E$ cannot be $2$.

Comment: (1) 3v = 2e (why?); (2) 2f = 6e (why?); (3) express v,f in terms of e; (4) v-e+f = 2 yields an easy contradiction.

Comment: @quasi: I did it in terms of $f$ but it is the same thing. There are $6$ vertices on every face and every vertex belongs to $3$ faces, hence $v=2f$. Every face has six edges and every edge belongs to two faces, hence $e=3f$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Your version is an ounce or two simpler, but I agree, in essence, they're the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Euler characteristic of a planar graph is $2$. However, if every face is hexagonal and every vertex has degree $3$, $V+F-E$ cannot be $2$, because it is 
$ 2F+F-3F = 0$.

Explanation: there are $6$ vertices on every face and every vertex belongs to $3$ faces, hence $V=2F$. Every face has six edges and every edge belongs to two faces, hence $E=3F$.

However, we have such kind of graph embedded in a torus (courtesy of [R. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/r-m)):

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]